# Check if variable does or does not exist

Tags: vbscript, sccm

I'm using an XML file that supports VBScript conditions, which I then use with SCCM task sequence variables.  From all the internet searching I've done, it's not entirely clear what I should be using to detect if a variable does or does not exist.  For example, I have two variables, one is called `%DriveIndex1%` and the other `%DriveIndex2%`.  These variables only exist if certain disk drives are detected.  So how does the code look to detect if either of those variables exist, or don't exist?  Here's a snippet:

```
<CheckboxInput Condition='%DriveIndex1% OR %DriveIndex2% <> ""' Variable="FormatAll" Question="Also partition and format the other drive(s)?" CheckedValue="True" UncheckedValue="False" Default="True" />
```

I don't think that condition is right, and I don't know if I should instead be using a function like `IsEmpty`, `IsObject`, or `IsNull`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%DriveIndex1% OR %DriveIndex2% <> ""` will not evaluate how you want. This syntax will evaluate two conditions, one `%DriveIndex1%` and the other `%DriveIndex2% <> ""`. You would need something like

`%DriveIndex1% <> "" OR %DriveIndex2% <> ""`

*but*

in vbscript `""` does not equal `Empty`, and undeclared variables are `Empty`, so if your TS variables do not exist you would want

`Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex1%) And Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex2%)`

You could also include checks for `Null` and `""` like this

`Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex1%) And Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex2%) and Not IsNull(%DriveIndex1%) And Not IsNull(%DriveIndex2%) And %DriveIndex1% <> "" And %DriveIndex2% <> ""`

Finally, I'm not familiar with how you're checking vbscript conditionals in xml, but to my knowledge TS variables are access through the `Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment` object similar to this

```
Set env = CreateObject("Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment")
env("MyVariable") = "value"
If env("MyOtherVariable") Then etc...
```

In this context, your condition would be

```
Not IsEmpty(env("DriveIndex1")) And Not IsEmpty(env("DriveIndex2"))
```

This is assuming whatever is calling the conditional from the xml file has already created the `env` object.

Comment: I don't think I need the env object, but I am curious how you would recommend using multiple "And" and "Or" statements in one line.  I just tried this one and it's not working: '(Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex0%) And Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex1%)) Or (Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex0%) And Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex2%)) Or (Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex1%) And Not IsEmpty(%DriveIndex2%))'

Comment: What exactly are you trying to determine? If any of them are empty?

Comment: So there are 3 total variables, and more than one of them has to NOT be empty.

Answer (score 1):

I would typically combine isEmpty and isNull to account for both:

```
if isnull(testvalue) or isempty(testvalue) then
    Response.Write "true"
else
    Response.Write "false"
end if
```

This is probably the easiest solution, though I have no experience with sccm...